# Ejabberd: Restrict who can view profile pictures

Tags: ejabberd

Is there any way to restrict who can view avatars?
I mean. Allowing only users within the same domain, or specific users to view profile pictures.

Answer (score 0):

Where are the avatars stored? I guess in the account vCard. In ejabberd this is handled by mod_vcard, and that module doesn't have any option for restricting who can view them.

Also, I don't see any other module that could modify or be configured for that specific task. There's mod_filter, but that acts at the stanza-type level: restrict who can send iq stanzas (required to view vCard, and many other tasks)...